# Load Javascript files in CakePHP Layout at "bottom"

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.2

Currently, I have a big CakePHP application with a layout and a lot of views. In the layout, I load Javascript files in the head which are needed by most views. In the views themself, I either load additional Javascript files (e.g., load a library file that is only needed there), or I add some Javascript code that is only relevant for this view in a script tag, for example if I need a click handler.

Since it is a known fact that loading Javascript files in the HTML head blocks loading the page, I wanted to put them at the bottom before closing the body Tag. But if I do so, the Javascript in my views that load the content breaks because it does not know about my loaded Javascript files. I understand that the Javascript code in the loaded views is executed before my files are loaded. But how can I prevent that?

I'm currently using the HTML Helper in the Layout (and everywhere else) to load my JS files like this:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->script('//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js'); ?>
```

And I use the JS Helper to "output" JS at the end of the page with

```
<?php echo $this->Js->writeBuffer(); ?>
```

Is there a way I can append my JS code in the views, so that it is executed when I call writeBuffer? Can that help me out?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is what I do in my view:

```
echo $this->Html->script('filename', array('inline' => false));
```

And this is what I do at the bottom of my layout:

```
echo $this->fetch('script');
```

Comment: I think this is a good solution and I think it works, if I put all my inline code in the views in Javascript files. Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 20):

Since CakePHP version 2.1 you can use script blocks:

```
// in your view
$this->Html->script('filename', array('block' => 'scriptBottom'));

// in your layout
echo $this->fetch('scriptBottom');
```

This approach lets you keep `echo $this->fetch('script')` in the `<head>` of your layout in case you need any scripts at the top.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In fact, I already found your answer somewhere in the web and integrated it, but it's sure worth to be mentioned here since it completes the answer.

Comment: Do you mean is it better to not load any js in the layout <head>, just fetch them at the end of the layour and call the js you need in each view?